# Как построить график с mathplotlib по данным полученным из другой функции?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, matplotlib, qt-designer

В коде получается список заголовков из **.csv** файла и по нажатию на элемент списка загружается таблица данными из этого **.csv**. 
Как можно построить график по этим данным?
Пытался объявлять глобальной переменной, но получал ошибку:

> NameError: name is not defined

Также пытался задавать на прямую элементы `tabletWidget`, но получал ошибку об невозможности итерации

**.csv** файл:

```
grad;test1;test2;test3
1;5;30;2
2;90;4;1
3;8;5;80
4;70;60;7
5;71,5;4;46
6;82,8;56,6;55,4
7;94,1;65,7;64,8
8;105,4;7;74,2
9;1;83,9;6
10;128;93;1
```

**main.py**

```
import csv
import sys
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from Ui_Window_tuple import Ui_MainWindow
global item
global deph

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(374, 327)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 374, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
    
class TEST(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TEST, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.select_file)
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.tab_data)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.graph)
        self.csv_reader_rows = []
        self.csv_reader_rows = []
        self.csv_reader_f_rows = []
        
    def select_file(self):
        print("1")

        self.f_name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.listWidget, 'ќткрыть csv', '.', 'csv(*.csv)')[0]
        if not self.f_name:
            return

        self.listWidget.clear()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)


        with open(self.f_name, newline='') as d:
            reader = csv.reader(d, delimiter=";")
            count = 0
            for row in reader:
                self.csv_reader_rows.append(row)
                if count == 0:
                    f'{" ".join(row)}'
                    for item in row:
                        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
                    else:
                        pass
                count += 1

    def tab_data(self, item):

        with open(self.f_name, newline='') as f:
            incl_col = [0]
            reader_deph = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
            for row in reader_deph:
                deph_d = list(row[i] for i in incl_col)
                self.csv_reader_f_rows.append(deph_d)

        numColumns = 2
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(numColumns)
        numRows = len(self.csv_reader_rows) - 1
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(numRows)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['A', 'B'])

        row = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        for i in range(numRows):
            for j in range(numColumns):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.csv_reader_rows[i + 1][row]))
                deph = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.csv_reader_f_rows[i + 1][0]))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 1, item)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, deph)
                self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
                self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()

        print("clic")

    def graph(self):
#        self.curve_graf.clear()
        x = []
        y = []

        x = item
        y = deph
        x.pop(0)
        y.pop(0)
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = TEST()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

необходимый результат достигается при следующих поправках:

```
def graph(self):
        x = []
        y = []

        with open("D:/TEST_project/test1csv.csv", newline='') as p:
            reader_p = csv.reader(p, delimiter=';')
            for rows in reader_p:
                y.append(rows[0])
                x.append(rows[2])
        x.pop(0)
        y.pop(0)
       
        a = [1, 2, 3]
        b = [1, 2, 3]
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.show()
```

Тогда получается такой график:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но это при строго заданных `row`, а необходимо, чтобы график строился на данных из `tabletWidget` по выбранному элементу из `listWidget` по нажатию кнопки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите/покажите какой график вы хотите построить, и какие действия надо сделать, чтобы построить график.

Comment: @S.Nick, совсем немного порезал форму, но для объяснения много не вырежешь, добавил небольшое пояснение. В общем я хочу понять как получить данные из другой функции, которые ранее загружались в таблицу, и строить по ним график.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я засомневался в правильности визуализации графиков, которые вы показали. 
Поэтому предоставил  вам два варианта:

- ```
        # это первый вариант графика
        x.append(item_x.text())
        y.append(item_y.text())
  ```
- ```
        # это второй вариант графика
        y.append(float(item_x.text().replace(',', '.')))
        x.append(float(item_y.text().replace(',', '.')))
  ```

Мне кажется вам нужен второй вариант.

```
import csv
import sys
# ??? import pandas as pd

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#import matplotlib as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                     # !!!

# ??? from Ui_Window_tuple import Ui_MainWindow
# ??? global item
# ??? global deph

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(374, 327)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 374, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

    
class TEST(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TEST, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.select_file)
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.tab_data)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.graph)
        
        self.csv_reader_rows = []
# ???         self.csv_reader_rows = []
        self.csv_reader_f_rows = []
        
    def select_file(self):
        print("1")
        self.f_name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self.listWidget, 'ќткрыть csv', '.', 'csv(*.csv)')[0]
        if not self.f_name:
            return

        self.listWidget.clear()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)

        with open(self.f_name, newline='') as d:
            reader = csv.reader(d, delimiter=";")
            count = 0
            for row in reader:
                self.csv_reader_rows.append(row)
                if count == 0:
                    f'{" ".join(row)}'
                    for item in row:
                        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
                    else:
                        pass
                count += 1

    def tab_data(self, item):
        with open(self.f_name, newline='') as f:
            incl_col = [0]
            reader_deph = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
            for row in reader_deph:
                deph_d = list(row[i] for i in incl_col)
                self.csv_reader_f_rows.append(deph_d)

        numColumns = 2
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(numColumns)
        numRows = len(self.csv_reader_rows) - 1
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(numRows)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['A', 'B'])

        row = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        for i in range(numRows):
            for j in range(numColumns):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.csv_reader_rows[i + 1][row]))
                deph = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.csv_reader_f_rows[i + 1][0]))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 1, item)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, deph)
                self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
                self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()
        print("clic")

    def graph(self):
#        self.curve_graf.clear()
        x = []
        y = []
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
        rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        for row in range(rows):
            item_y = self.tableWidget.item(row, 0)
            item_x = self.tableWidget.item(row, 1)
            
            #print(f'{item_y.text()} -- {item_x.text()}') # 
            
            ''' 
            # это первый вариант графика
            x.append(item_x.text())
            y.append(item_y.text())
            '''
            # это второй вариант графика
            y.append(float(item_x.text().replace(',', '.')))
            x.append(float(item_y.text().replace(',', '.')))            
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  

        '''
# ???        x = item
# ???        y = deph
# ???        x.pop(0)
# ???        y.pop(0)
        '''
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = TEST()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Это первый вариант графика:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Это ВТОРОЙ вариант графика:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]